# Class 'row' won't work Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems with 'row' class. It simply won't put controls in one row.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Department", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    <p>Search by: </p>
                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="Name" /> <text>Name</text>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of one row I got this:

[image]

What I am doing wrongly here?

Comment: the `.row` class in bootstrap is not for aligning input elements, it is used for the Bootstrap grid system. Have a look at the grid system here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the inputs, not the `row`. Just use `form-inline`..

```
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-inline">

                    <p>Search by: </p>
                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="Name">
                    <text>Name</text>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">

                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/zRpkQFvmes